# Create Task on account as soon as created on Case

Tags: case, account, related-list, tasks

I have got requirement where I want to create task on Account object as soon as someone creates on case record. In general I want to list all tasks from several Cases under one account. Is there any out of the box way in salesforce to do that? For example attachment can automatically associate with account if attached in any case because of account case parent-child relationship. Is the same thing possible in Task?

Comment: You can do a trigger after insert on Case. Get the Account from the Case record. Create Task with WhatId = the account that you got from the case.

Comment: Trigger on Case? Or trigger on task?

Comment: On Case, 'cause you want to create a Task after creating a Case. So, the trigger will be an after insert on Case.

Comment: Or process builder as said in answer below.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. I want to create task on account when someone create task on a Case object. So account will display all the task from its child cases. While individual case will only display task related to that particular Case record.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via Process Builder on creation of  a case.

```
Object: Case
Run on Creation
No criteria, always run
Action: Create Record (task)
    Related To ID: Reference [Case}.AccountId
    Status: Closed
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. I want to create task on account when someone create task on a Case object. So account will display all the task from its child cases. While individual case will only display task related to that particular Case record.